# My VM's WiFi will not connect

Tags: networking

When I run wpa_cli and just watch what's going on, I keep seeing

```
Connection to wpa_supplicant lost - trying to reconnect
Warning: Failed to attach to wpa_supplicant.
Connection to wpa_supplicant re-established
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="RPI-WiFi1"
<3>Trying to associate with e4:5f:01:9f:d8:08 (SSID='RPI-WiFi1' freq=2412 MHz)
<3>CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="RPI-WiFi1" auth_failures=8 duration=116 reason=CONN_FAILED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
> 'PING' command timed out.
```

Is there a source of information on what CONN_FAILED means, or is the Connection to wpa_supplicant lost telling me that wpa_supplicant is the problem?

Comment: VMs usually do not directly access wireless network devices unless you have configured the VM to have exclusive access to the device. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the OS of the host (2) which VM engine you're using (3) any configuration settings that are related to networking. Without this basic level of detail, it will not be feasible to offer potential solutions 

Comment: CONN_FAILED means connection failed. It looks like you have the network login password wrong, as I see "auth_failures=8".